# how to handle ERROR: Duplicate entry in spring jpa

Tags: java, jpa, exception

I was trying to execute below code :

```
public void createScarceVouchers(long numberOfVouchers,int productId,String fileType,int userId) {
        EntityManager entityManager=this.emf.createEntityManager();

        try {
        entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
        Product product  = productService.getProductById(productId);
        UserMaster userMaster = userMasterService.getOrignalUserMasterById(userId);
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        int batchSize = 30;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            Voucher voucher = null;
            String strVoucher  = AcfUtils.getRandom();
            if(i>=2 && i<=5) {
                strVoucher = "abcdefg";
                System.out.println(i+">   abcdefgh");
                voucher = new Voucher(product, userMaster, strVoucher, 'G',new Date());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(i+">    "+strVoucher);
                voucher = new Voucher(product, userMaster, strVoucher, 'G',new Date());
            }

            entityManager.persist(voucher);
             if (i % batchSize == 0 && i > 0) {
                    entityManager.flush();
                    entityManager.clear();
                }
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
        finally {

            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
```

And I was getting below exception.

`ERROR: Duplicate entry 'abcdefg' for key 'voucher_UNIQUE'`

**full stack trace:**

```
Apr 12, 2018 1:55:24 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Apr 12, 2018 1:55:24 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry 'abcdefg' for key 'voucher_UNIQUE'
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:767)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy746.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.wpits.acf.core.repository.VoucherRepositoryImpl.createScarceVouchers(VoucherRepositoryImpl.java:155)
    at com.wpits.acf.core.repository.VoucherRepositoryImpl.createAndLoadVouchers(VoucherRepositoryImpl.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy765.createAndLoadVouchers(Unknown Source)
    at com.wpits.acf.voucher.service.VoucherService.getVoucher(VoucherService.java:31)
    at com.wpits.acf.voucher.service.VoucherService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$74efb376.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669)
    at com.wpits.acf.voucher.service.VoucherService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3b6f443.getVoucher(<generated>)
    at com.wpits.acf.voucher.controller.VoucherController.createAndLoadVoucers(VoucherController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.wpits.acf.core.security.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2919)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3490)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'abcdefg' for key 'voucher_UNIQUE'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:533)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1826)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1970)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5001)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1955)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 104 more
```

I intentionally wanted this exception. Means, I was storing some keys to my `Map` collection. And if there exists the same key in DB then I wanted to remove that particular key from map. 
So here I wanted to collect `abcdefg` from exception so that I can remove it from Map. Also this exception/error is marked in red color. How can I handle it to collect that value in my catch block.

**voucher class**

```
package com.wpits.acf.core.model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "voucher", catalog = "anti_counter_feit",uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="voucher"))
public class Voucher implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6070909016660043843L;
    private Integer id;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Product product;
    @JsonIgnore
    private UserMaster userMaster;
    private String voucher;
    private String consumedBy;
    private char status;
    private Date createdOn;
    private Date updatedOn;

    public Voucher() {
    }

    public Voucher(Product product, UserMaster userMaster, String voucher, char status, Date createdOn) {
        this.product = product;
        this.userMaster = userMaster;
        this.voucher = voucher;
        this.status = status;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public Voucher(Product product, UserMaster userMaster, String voucher, String consumedBy, char status,
            Date createdOn, Date updatedOn) {
        this.product = product;
        this.userMaster = userMaster;
        this.voucher = voucher;
        this.consumedBy = consumedBy;
        this.status = status;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
    public UserMaster getUserMaster() {
        return this.userMaster;
    }

    public void setUserMaster(UserMaster userMaster) {
        this.userMaster = userMaster;
    }

    @Column(name = "voucher", nullable = false,unique=true, length = 45)
    public String getVoucher() {
        return this.voucher;
    }

    public void setVoucher(String voucher) {
        this.voucher = voucher;
    }

    @Column(name = "consumed_by", length = 15)
    public String getConsumedBy() {
        return this.consumedBy;
    }

    public void setConsumedBy(String consumedBy) {
        this.consumedBy = consumedBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public char getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(char status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return this.createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_on", length = 19)
    public Date getUpdatedOn() {
        return this.updatedOn;
    }

    public void setUpdatedOn(Date updatedOn) {
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like your voucherStr is a key field and in your code it is not unique between 2-5(inclusive), which could be the cause of this exception.

Comment: as I said, I intentionally wanted to repeat voucher string for 2-5

Comment: actually there will be very long list of vouchers to be persisted in db. these vouchers have to be unique. if in case same voucher found in db, then I should collect that voucher string in catch block. remove it from my map collection and set a new voucher instead. and again try to persist the vouchers again

Comment: You can catch ConstraintViolationException for your case but getting the value from the exception somehow doesn't seems right. One thing you can do is increase the scope of voucher object and reduce the try catch to get this specific exception. Then you can propogate/handle the exception and get the value from voucher.